# Passing an array from Child to Parent in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an array in child component which I need to pass to parent. Is the below approach correct because I am sending the array and not the object ?

Child JS

```
@track myArray = [ //elements inside ];

handleEvent(event){
    // handling the changes in array and passing it to parent
    const custEvent = new CustomEvent('change', {
      detail : this.myArray
    })
   this.dispatchEvent(custEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is correct and it will work. however, it is recommended to send primitive data types. [Create and Dispatch Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch)

> The CustomEvent interface imposes no type requirements or structure on
> the detail property. However it’s important to send only primitive
> data. JavaScript passes all data types by reference except for
> primitives. If a component includes an object in its detail property,
> any listener can mutate that object without the component’s knowledge.
> This is a bad thing! It’s a best practice either to send only
> primitives, or to copy data to a new object before adding it to the
> detail property. Copying the data to a new object ensures that you’re
> sending only the data you want, and that the receiver can’t mutate
> your data.

So, I recommend to make a copy of your array and send it:

```
@track myArray = [ //elements inside ];

handleEvent(event){
    // handling the changes in array and passing it to parent
    const custEvent = new CustomEvent('change', {
      detail : [...this.myArray]
    })
   this.dispatchEvent(custEvent);
}
```